# Suppose $P(x)=x^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kx^k$. Find $\lim_{x\to \infty}[(P(x)^{\frac1n})-x]$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

My work:

This problem fundamentally confuses me. I cannot how to deal with $n$. Does it stand for any arbitrary integer, or is it assumed to grow to infinity, similar to a sequence? Regardless, I feel as though I am missing a key element to solving this problem.
Moving forward, my first technique was to determine the first few terms of $P(x)$. This led to $$P(x)=x^n+(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_{n-1}x^{n-1})$$From here, is it possible to group the $x^n$ terms together and figure something out using big O notation? After that, I  have to deal with $P(x)$ being taken to then nth root with is confusing to me as well. I am rather confused on how to progress on the problem, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n$ is just a fixed integer (and arbitrary), it does not change here: it is fixed once and for all in the problem.

Now, a possible solution: first, factor.
$$
P(x) = x^n \left(1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k x^{k-n}\right)
$$
so that
$$
P(x)^{\frac{1}{n}} = x \left(1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k x^{k-n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
and 
$$
P(x)^{\frac{1}{n}} -x = x\left(1+y\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} - x
$$
with $y=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k x^{k-n} \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 0$. You get, by a Taylor expansion of first order around $0$, that $(1+y)^{1/n} = 1+ \frac{y}{n} + o(y)$ *(recall that $n$ is a constant, the variable here is $y$)*, and therefore
$$
P(x)^{\frac{1}{n}} -x = x+ x\frac{y}{n} + o(xy) - x = 
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{a_k}{n} x^{k-n+1} + o(xy)
$$
But in the sum, all terms go to $0$, except the one corresponding to $k=n-1$ (since then $x^{k-n+1} = 1$). That is,
$$
P(x)^{\frac{1}{n}} -x = 
\frac{a_{n-1}}{n} + o(1)
$$
giving you the limit.